# ROS impromptu_buttons issue

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros answers,
all examples of kinect_demos packages are almost correct, but 2 in particular do not work: "impromptu_buttons" and "piano". I have already installed the Simple Fast Media Library to play sounds, but when i try to install the dependencies using rosdep, I get the following response:

*~$ rosdep install impromptu_buttons*

*Failed to find rosdep libsfmt for package impromptu_buttons on OS:ubuntu version:11.04
ERROR: ABORTING: Rosdeps [u'libsfmt'] could not be resolved*

It is a problem due to my OS or should I install something else?
Please help me!

Thanks for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10354/ros-impromptu_buttons-issue/) by [Plasson](https://answers.ros.org/users/731/plasson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your are missing a rosdep file that defines how to download libsfmt for your OS.
If there is a rosdep.yaml file with the package, it might also only been missing the entry for 11.04 (but has a one for libsfmt). In that case you can just add the entry.

If there is no rosdep.yaml, and you know that the library you installed is the one that it is looking for, you can remove the dependency from the manifest.xml or write a rosdep file for that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0